# Undefined method in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting undefined method error when I try to call method as:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return{
        method1: function(){ return true; }
        method2: function(){
           if(this.method1()){
               return true;
           }
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

However if I define method1 as a private method and try to call it from method2 it works.

```
module.exports = function () {
    var method1 = function(){ return true; };
    return{
        method2: function(){
           if(this.method1()){
               return true;
           }
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Why I am getting undefined method error when I try to call public method from public method?

Comment: both are running correctly for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    module.exports = function () {
        return{
            method1: function(){ return true; }
            method2: function(){
              var self= this;
               if(self.method1()){
                   return true;
               }
               return false;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: That actually worked! Thanks. Can you just tell me why do I need to save reference before?

Comment: To change the context  of this.self now belong to same context so this is done.